# Difficulties on running android demo project on Eclipse and latest Android SDK

Tags: android, sample, demo

I have issues on running android demo from sdk, It doesnt work at all. It's always shows errors. So after couple of online search i find this link
[How to run the Android Support4Demo in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593431/how-to-run-the-android-support4demo-in-eclipse)
Based on the tutorial, I follow his tutorial and expecting it would work like others.
For information, my eclipse is eclipse indigo 3.7.2 with latest android sdk.

but i have this errors, lot of errors:

[Click here for image of list error](http://postimage.org/image/43i32olzb/)

does anybody have any idea how to make me able to run android demo project ?

thanks

Comment: buddy first time kindly make a simple hello world application or other simple app

Comment: i've already tried the hello world app. It just i need some kind of gallery effect for the main menu (first page). And also the issue only happens when I'm tried to run the android example (demo) project, not for the normal projects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't build a right android project. Eclipse can't load the android.jar, so classed of android can not be found

Comment: How to make sure the .jar is right or not ? Can I just copy another project's jar to this project to make the sample work ?